# How can I keep my Box auth persistently valid?

Tags: box-api

I have an application that enables users to upload files to MY Box account.

How can I keep my backend service persistently logged in (or have login be fully automated) so I can always upload files?

Answer (score 1):

There are really 2 possibilities.

1) Don't use your account for other peoples content.  If they own those cat pictures, then you really should have those users either give you their email addresses and use [Box's "Provision" grant](https://developers.box.com/provision/), that gives you a folder-token to access an application folder in that users account.  Or have your users sign-in with real OAuth2. It is getting easier to work with OAuth2, especially with it cooked into the [SDKs](http://developers.box.com/sdks/)

2) If you are really doing a server-to-server integration, and you own all the content that users send into your application, then you should logon once as yourself, and store the AT/RT in a secure [keystore](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11517/storage-of-secrets-keystores-hsms-and-the-rest).  After that, as long as your server connects to Box at least once every 60 days, your tokens will never die.  Access Tokens live for an hour, but Refresh Tokens live for 60 days or until used.  Again, the [SDKS](http://developers.box.com/sdks/) take care of the token refreshes for you, so you really don't have to worry about this unless you are calling the [raw Box REST APIs](http://developers.box.com/docs/).